# 2d/ 3d Development for smartphones NOT using Unity?

Tags: android, ios, 3d, 2d, smartphone

I am interested in finding efficient 2d/3d engines to be used on smartphones / tablets, other than Unity are there any other cross platform options for game developers? Any links to USEFUL websites would be much appreciated. I already am familiar using Direct X / Open GL on PC.

Answer (score 0):

UDK is a pretty good option, I think. It's the fully featured Unreal Engine 3, for free (unless you want it for commercial use, then you give them % of your profits, I believe). It also runs on Android an iOS.

[Unreal Development Kit for mobile](http://www.unrealengine.com/mobile/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) for 2d development. Its community may help.

For 3D, I used [jPCT](http://www.jpct.net/jpct-ae/index.html) which makes integration of 3ds, obj or other 3d models really easy.

[Unreal Development Kit for mobile](http://www.unrealengine.com/mobile/) stays for advanced 3d/game developers... but kick some asses!

I honestly didn't took the time to take a look at UDK so I can't recommend it because when I needed a 3d framework for Android, it wasn't available yet and I needed to have a "standard" Android application for a plane manufacturer in which a button launch the game (a fly simulator rendering their products), the game mustn't be standalone (customer's wish).

It's something to think about before jumping in a new tool : Does it fits all my needs?